# Three.js show sRGB colors wrong

Tags: three.js, png, color-space, srgb

I have problem with PNG sRGB rednering in Three.js. I have this piece of code where I am generation texture from SVG file:

```
(...) // managing whole SVG data which is long and not important as I will show below
window.temCanvas =  document.createElement('canvas');
temCanvas.width = '2048';
temCanvas.height = '454';
window.temContext = temCanvas.getContext('2d', {colorSpace: "srgb", preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
temContext.clearRect(0, 0, 2048, 454);
temContext.drawImage(newTextureTopSVG, 0,0, 2048, 454);

var newTex1 = temCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // here should be info about sRGB?
```

Texture generated this way is showing different colors. All 0 and 255 values are showing correctly but when it is between i.e. rgb(0,128,255) should look like this:

[image]

but it is rendered as:

[image]

I saved png generated from SVG and compared it to similar png generated from graphic software, there is difference which I see in Notepad++, correct file contain this:
[image]
file which is rendering badly (after saving from canvas in Firefox) doesn't contain srgb text:
[image]

I suppose I have to add sRGB info here:

```
var newTex1 = temCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

How to do it? But shouldn't it be always sRGB for PNG?

Maybe I am wrong and it is possible to force Three.js to show colors correctly by changing something in Material, Texture etc.?

I am using:

```
renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;
```

I don't want to provide all data, I will edit this post if needed. It is way too long. Especially managing SVG data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;`, sRGB encoded color textures must be configured like so:

```js
texture.encoding = sRGBEncoding;
```

Otherwise the sRGB workflow is incomplete resulting in wrong colors.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Maybe it will help someone:
const loader = new TextureLoader();

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => loader.load(newTex1,
function ( texture ) {
  materialUp.map = texture;
  texture.encoding = sRGBEncoding;
  texture.flipY =false;
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  materialUp.needsUpdate = true;

  resolve(texture);
},
undefined,
function ( err ) {
  console.error( 'An error happened: ' );
}),
                function (error) {
                    console.log('error: ');
                }